# Why does the else statement still play if the if statement in python for a while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I decided to make a mini-game as my 1st program since I am very new to python. The user must enter yes to start the game if you type no the program is supposed to say "bye-bye" and end. if anything else is entered it print "I do not understand bye-bye" However when I enter no it plays the else statement along with what was supposed to play when it enters no. How do I fix this? This is my program (sorry if it's a little long). You can run it and type no to see what I mean.

```
light_on = False
door_open = False
print('hello')
start = input('Would you like to play a game yes or no ? ').lower() 
if start == 'no':
    print('bye bye')
while start == 'yes':
    print('Type help if you do not know how to play')
    command = input('Command?: ').lower()
    if command == 'help':
        print('''
on = turn light on
off = turn light off
open = open door
close = close door''')
    elif command == 'on':
        if light_on:
            print('The light is already on')
        else:
            light_on = True
            print('The light is bright and warming')
    elif command == 'off':
        if not light_on:
            print('the light is already off')
        else:
            light_on = False
            print('the room is dark and scary')
    elif command == 'open':
        if door_open:
            print('the door is already open!')
        else:
            door_open = True
            print('the hallway is so dark you cannot see')
    elif command == 'close':
        if not door_open:
            print('the door is already closed!')
        else:
            door_open = False
            print('you slammed the door shut')
    elif command == 'quit':
        print('bye bye')
        break
    else:
        print('I do not understand')
else:
    print('I do not understand bye bye')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `else:` statement of a `while` loop is executed whenever the loop ends due to the condition failing, rather than being stopped by a `break` statement. Since `no` doesn't match the `while start == 'yes':` condition, the loop ends immediately, and the `while` is executed.

You should use `elif` rather than `while` for the `yes` option, then the final `else` will be connected to this `if` chain.

```
light_on = False
door_open = False
print('hello')
start = input('Would you like to play a game yes or no ? ').lower() 
if start == 'no':
    print('bye bye')
elif start == 'yes':
    print('Type help if you do not know how to play')
    command = input('Command?: ').lower()
    if command == 'help':
        print('''
on = turn light on
off = turn light off
open = open door
close = close door''')
    elif command == 'on':
        if light_on:
            print('The light is already on')
        else:
            light_on = True
            print('The light is bright and warming')
    elif command == 'off':
        if not light_on:
            print('the light is already off')
        else:
            light_on = False
            print('the room is dark and scary')
    elif command == 'open':
        if door_open:
            print('the door is already open!')
        else:
            door_open = True
            print('the hallway is so dark you cannot see')
    elif command == 'close':
        if not door_open:
            print('the door is already closed!')
        else:
            door_open = False
            print('you slammed the door shut')
    elif command == 'quit':
        print('bye bye')
        break
    else:
        print('I do not understand')
else:
    print('I do not understand bye bye')
```